# This boxmodel problem in IE 7 whats the best way to deal with it?

Tags: css

http://dev.harveys.co.uk/clients/

## clients { margin-right:-20px; }

## clients .client { float:left; background:#9d9fa2; width:190px; margin:0 8px 8px 0; }

## clients .client .inner { min-height:80px; }

.inner { padding:10px; }

## clients .last-child { margin-right:0; }

## clients .client img { margin-bottom:5px; border:1px solid #aaa; }

```
<div id="page">
        
    <div id="clients" class="clearfix">
        <?php $count = 0;?>
        <?php query_posts('category_name=Clients&showposts=20&orderby=297,299,308,302,304'); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>  
        <?php $count++; ?>
        <div class="client <?php if ( $count % 3 == 0 ){ echo "last-child"; }?>">
<div class="inner">
    <img src="" alt="" width="168" height="104" alt="" /></a>
    <h2></h2>
```

```
    </div><!-- clients -->
    </div><!-- page -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link is dead. The best way in general is to use IE6/7 CSS stylesheets (sparingly) using this technique: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Most IE specific CSS bugs are listed here: http://css-tricks.com/ie-css-bugs-thatll-get-you-every-time/

Comment: Yes that is what I have use Alex, the conditional statements, because of my dead link you couldn't see that sorry about that.

Comment: still getting issues with the new url. Let me know what it is and I'll have a look